# Read Ms word document with images using php

Tags: php, ms-word, ms-office, filereader

I have a chunk of code that I'm using to read MS Office Word documents.

It is reading only text not all the contents.

```
<?php
function read_file_docx($filename){

    $striped_content = '';
    $content = '';
    if(!$filename || !file_exists($filename)) return false;
    $zip = zip_open($filename);
    if (!$zip || is_numeric($zip)) return false;
while ($zip_entry = zip_read($zip)) {
        if (zip_entry_open($zip, $zip_entry) == FALSE) continue;
        if (zip_entry_name($zip_entry) != "word/document.xml") continue;
        $content .= zip_entry_read($zip_entry, zip_entry_filesize($zip_entry));
        zip_entry_close($zip_entry);
    }

    zip_close($zip);
    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p></w:tc><w:tc>', " ", $content);
    $content = str_replace('</w:r></w:p>', "\r\n", $content);
    $striped_content = strip_tags($content);

    return $striped_content;
}
```

$filename = "customers.docx";

```
$content = read_file_docx($filename);
if($content !== false) {

    echo nl2br($content);   
}
else {
    echo 'Couldn\'t the file. Please check that file.';
}

?>
```

I want to read images,graphs and all the contents  as well and display it in a webpage.

Comment: When you say read, what exactly do you mean?  Are you trying to get the pieces of the document, or are you intending to present the document in its original format and structure?

Comment: I am intended to present the whole document with all the contents in it.

Comment: The only way to reliably do that is to fire up a copy of Word and use its API.  You could spend years working on this otherwise.  Just ask the folks contributing to OpenOffice about that.  :-D

Comment: Actually I have seen but I didn't got any API's  to read word document  . Can you suggest me, if you know any.

Comment: Have you looked into converting the docs into a PDF and displaying the PDF on your site?

Comment: @user It was nice but I want to display it in a webpage not in adobe reader.

Comment: What do you expect the return type of `read_file_docx()` to be? HTML? Perhaps you're better off using a DOC to HTML library: http://www.phplivedocx.org/

Answer (score 2):

I think you should first change your doc documents to pdf with command line Open Office or 
Libre Office.

with Libre Office it would be:

```
libreoffice --headless --convert-to pdf your_file_name.doc
```

and then use pdf.js ( https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/  ) to display documents on your site ( you don't need adobe reader )

Here is another minimal example
https://github.com/vivin/pdfjs-text-selection-demo ( read minimal.js file to understand how the pdf is inserted )

Second option is to convert doc into docx and use https://github.com/stephen-hardy/DOCX.js

Comment: it's good but I saw in some sites they are displaying  doc files  and providing edit option.

Comment: @Mahendra updated answer with docx.js

Comment: Regarding editing they are a few commercial projects + http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feng_Office_Community_Edition

Answer (score 1):

In case you are trying to do the extraction of all document content and the conversion into a matching web display all by yourself, I suggest reading the format specifications by Microsoft.

- Office Open XML is an ISO/IEC and ECMA standard (ECMA even provides the documents for free) and can be found here: http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-376.htm
- The "old" binary Office formats are available from Microsoft directly: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc313118.aspx

---

If you're just looking for a convenient way of extracting the contents from an MS Word document, I would strongly suggest looking into a library that already handles the document processing and extraction.

There are 2 projects that I know of that are working on the processing of MS Office documents in PHP.

- [PHPOffice / PHPWord](https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPWord) (I'm not sure how far the Word branch of the project has developed. The project originated in a smaller scale supporting only MS Excel, but they are now working on Word and PowerPoint as well)
- [PHPDocX](http://www.phpdocx.com/documentation/features) (This is a split project. You can get an LGPL licensed version with a basic feature set or a commercial paid-for version which should handle most things you find in common word documents)

HTH

Comment: @Mastacheta I tried this its supporting upto MS-word 2007 not higher versions any have thanks for suggestions

Comment: @Mahendra is there anything specific you need that's only available in Office 2010 or 2013? I've always thought the file formats were both forward and backward compatible.

Answer (score 1):

You should check out [Aspose Cloud](http://www.aspose.com/cloud/word-api.aspx). 
Its a service that allows you to convert docx to html

There is a [PHP SDK](https://github.com/asposeforcloud/Aspose_Cloud_SDK_For_PHP) for it on github.

There is a free option if you are converting less than 100 documents per month

good luck